# Retrieve HTML drop down list value with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have an HTML dropdown list which i'm populating from a database. My question is how can i retrieve the value of a selected item from this dropdown list using AJAX? 
My javascript:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function getData(str){
var xhr = false;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else {

        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (xhr) {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET", "/display-product.php?q="+str, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    }
}
</script>
```

The dropdown list in display-product.php:

```
<div>
      <?php
       echo '<select title="Select one" name="selectcat" onChange="getData(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">';
       while($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc()){            
       echo '<option value="' . $row1['id'] . '">' . $row1['category'] . '</option>';
        }
       echo '</select>';
        ?>
        </div>
```

The div to display the selected item:

```
<div class="product_directory" id="div1"></div>
```

I'm not very conversant with AJAX. I tried to access the "str" variable passed to the getData function in my PHP script using `"$string = $_GET['q']"` but still didn't work. Thanks in advance for the help.

UPDATE: i was able the figure out the source of the problem: I have two functions that populate the select lists from the database. When a user selects an option from the first dropdown(with id="categoriesSelect"), the second one(id = "subcatsSelect") is automatically populated. Here is the code for both functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
echo "var categories = $jsonCats; \n";
echo "var subcats = $jsonSubCats; \n";
?>
function loadCategories(){
    var select = document.getElementById("categoriesSelect");
    select.onchange = updateSubCats;
    for(var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
      select.options[i] = new Option(categories[i].val,categories[i].id);          
    }
}
function updateSubCats(){
    var catSelect = this;
    var catid = this.value;
    var subcatSelect = document.getElementById("subcatsSelect");
    subcatSelect.options.length = 0; //delete all options if any present
    for(var i = 0; i < subcats[catid].length; i++){
      subcatSelect.options[i] = new Option(subcats[catid][i].val,subcats[catid][i].id);
    }
  }
</script>
```

The code works fine if i manually put  in the select list . But using these two functions to pull from the database, nothing is displayed. I call the loadCategories() function like this
`<body onload = "loadCategories()">`.
The other select box is very similar to this one.
 I don't know the specific issue but i know it's coming either from loadCategories() or updateSubCats().

Comment: why are you not using JQuery?

Comment: Nothing wrong with not using jquery

Comment: Try to listen what your browser really send to a server when `onChange` event triggered. Take a look please, does variable `q` send and contain something? This could help localize a trouble.

Comment: Could you add the display-product.php full code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/Hww3E/1/) is retrieving the value on the select. But it fails on your function.

I tried using that open function [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first). But, in my side it didn't work using an slash (/). So, try to remove that and try it.

...

```
 xhr.open("GET", "display-product.php?q="+str, true);
```

...

**EDIT:** full working code...

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function getData(str){
var xhr = false;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else {

        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (xhr) {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET", "display-product.php?q="+str, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    }
}
</script>

<select title="Select one" name="selectcat" onChange="getData(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div id="div1"></div>
```

... on display-product.php

```
echo $_GET['q'];
```

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9bRAT/) for the edited part of your question.

And [this other](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QbMJBq) to make it work together.

Hope this helps.

Comment: that didn't work either Luigi.. were u able to get the value of q using $_GET['q']? or it just worked without the slash on your end?

Comment: Mine doesn't work and the code is pretty much the same.. i wonder what's wrong

Comment: ... It's the same, i took it from you :) The only difference is that slash I mentioned you before. Also, verify the html that is been generated in PHP.

Comment: I figured out the source of the problem but not the solution. I've made an update to the question. Do you have an idea about what's wrong?

Comment: yea Luigi but the selected content doesn't get displayed even with your proposed method. But when i manually put the options in <options></options>. The selected content displays fine. I don't know why.

Comment: i want to retrieve the value of the selected content from a dropdown list and display it right? The code worked for you but not for me because i had my lists populated with javascript just as your "Fiddle" example. My issue is when i populate the list just as the "Fiddle" example, i'm unable to display the value of the selected content but when i put my options using the <options> tag i'm able to retrieve and display the value of the selected content. I want to be able to have my lists populated just as the "Fiddle" example and still be able to display the value of the selected content.

Comment: For example in the demo you made in "Fiddle". If i select "two" and "uno". I want to be able to print:
**You selected: two >> uno.**

Comment: Ok. But, do you want to print it with display-product.php?

Comment: Understood. But keeping the same line, you can try [THIS CODE](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YzWAuT). I explained the changes in a few comments.

Comment: works almost perfectly. I'm so grateful. thanks so much. i tried to get the text value in the categories dropdown in getData() by changing `var select1 = document.getElementById("categoriesSelect").value;` to `var select1 = document.getElementById("categoriesSelect").text;` but i got an "undefined" output instead. any idea why?

Comment: Yes, because the select doesn't have a text value, the option does. So, try with [THIS CODE](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QbMJBq). I'll edit my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a this possible solution with JQuery:

1. Add the attribute "id" in option tag in php code and remove onChange function:

   `echo "<select id='mySelect' title='Select one' name='selectcat'>";`
2. Add Jquery File [JQuery 1.9.1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js) and add the javascript HTML tag
3. Put before close tag body:

   `$(document).ready( function() {

       $('#mySelect').change(function(){`

   ```
     var $selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
     var selectedLabel = $selectedOption.text();
     var selectedValue = $selectedOption.val();
     alert(selectedValue + ' - ' + selectedLabel);
     $('.product_directory').html(selectedValue + ' - ' + selectedLabel);
      $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url:"display-product.php",
       data:selectedValue OR selectedLabel,
       success:function(response){
           alert('Succes send');
       }
     })
     return false;
   });
   ```

   `});`
4. Read in php:

   echo $_POST['selectedValue'];

   or

   echo $_POST['selectedLabel'];

Comment: thanks but i don't understand what you mean; plus the jquery 1.9.1 is too huge a file..

Comment: "Put after close tag body the next script:" Do you mean after the </body> tag?

Comment: Refresh the page, Im modified the text, excuse me, my english it's so bad. Caution in ajax send, in data:selectedValue OR selectedLabel, choose only one

Comment: I haven't used jquery before. How do i implement step2 i.e: "Add Jquery File JQuery 1.9.1 and add the javascript HTML tag"

Comment: Go to the link I wrote in my answer and press Ctrl + and Ctrl+c after, you've got the cilpboard .. creates a jquery.js file in the root of your project, and paste the code ..
now from the html file make the call:
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> that line goes before the script